# How to implement iCal in objective C

Tags: iphone, objective-c, icalendar

I am working on a project, in which I need to keep the date and time of particular days. for this purpose I planned to implement iCal in objective-C so that I can get all the information from an iCal server.

Can anyone please tell me how to do this programatically?

Comment: Sorry, but on SO, we don't write complete applications for you. Start doing it yourself, and if you have specific problems, ask them.

Comment: @H2CO3 I didn't ask for total code. i am just asking some tutorial to assist me to code. I have googled it but i didn't get the exact iCal code for implementation

Comment: You start working. If you will have a problem at any point then we will always happy to help.

Comment: StackOverflow.com isn't for open-ended questions. If you don't know more specifically what you're looking for, do some research on your own -- for example, have you looked into whether any of the iOS builtin frameworks can do what you need? (Like EventKit or maybe just NSDateComponents, depending on what you're after.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a library, such as libiCal http://www.citadel.org/doku.php?id=documentation:featured_projects:libical

If you want to implement yourself there's three RFCs (RFC 2445, 2446, and 2447) so it's not likely to be a quick job.